# Almost everywhere convergent Fourier series

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Apparently there is a deep theorem stating:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a function satisfying $f(x)=f(x+2\pi)$ and $\int_0^{2\pi}|f(x)|^2dx<\infty$. Then the Fourier series of $f$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

Now it is easy to prove that the Fourier series converges in $L^2$-norm, but proving almost everywhere convergence requires a lot of machinery, I have been told. My first question is, what kind of machinery is involved. My second question relates to the following equivalent formulation of the theorem:

Let $\varepsilon>0$, then there exists a number $\delta>0$ such that for all $a_k\in\mathbb{C}$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, satisfying $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|a_k|^2<\delta$, the set
$$\Big\{x\in[0,2\pi]:\;\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Big|\sum_{k=-n}^na_ke^{ikx}\Big|>1\Big\}$$
has Lebesgue measure smaller than $\varepsilon$.

So my second question is whether anything is known about how small $\delta$ should be for a given $\varepsilon$?

Of course one could ask similar questions about the Fourier transform.

Edit: I think I can answer my own questions. It is clear from what I find on the internet about Carleson's theorem that it can be proved using rather concrete techniques. The following document that proves the boundedness of the Carleson operator is only 10 pages: [link](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/2000/0007/0004/MRL-2000-0007-0004-a001.pdf).

As for my second question, the bound on the Carleson operator could be made concrete which would yield a concrete number $C$, independent of the $a_k$, such that
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Big|\sum_{k=-n}^na_ke^{ikx}\Big|^2dx\leq C\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty|a_k|^2.$$

And then the number $\delta$ could be taken to be $\varepsilon/C$.

Comment: You want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem

Comment: Thank you for that